# Compiler doesnt recognize __STATIC_INLINE

Tags: c, gcc

I have a C project which was running on ARM architecture using the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler and now I am trying to compile it natively on windows using the gnu99 compiler because i need to unit test and it was difficult to do it on the actual hardware.

However the compiler is not recogonziing the static inline commands although i included the inline flag in my makefile, as follows: `CFLAGS += -fgnu89-inline`

Below is the error i am getting:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void' __STATIC_INLINE void
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to let the compiler recognize the inline commands?

Comment: Do you use workbench like IAR?  It allows simulation on Windows.  So same software code can be compiled within IAR.

Comment: I dont think so as i dont know what it is. I will look into it now.

Comment: Look at the header files that the current code is using.  Those files are most likely  hardware specific header files which gcc doesn't provide.

Comment: That is correct their are some hardware specific header files and they also use some ARM specific instructions such as SVCALL. Im trying to isolate them though for the purpose of unit testing. Is IAR something similar to a Simulator/Emulator?

Comment: Yes.  There is a bit of learning curve.  But I don't see any other way.  You are doing tests on Windows for the code that is running on ARM.  So the best thing is to bring the similar soft ARM environment.  Otherwise, you have to redefine all these macro which you don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `__STATIC_INLINE` is not a part of standard C.  You either need to provide a macro definition for it, or you should replace `__STATIC_INLINE` with `static inline`.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible for me to do that, as that code is coming from an SDK library i'm using designed by Nordic Semiconductors. Not easy for me to change it as it is present in numerous places

Comment: Like I said, you can also provide a macro definition for it.  You can put `-D__STATIC_INLINE='static inline'` in your compiler options or find an appropriate place in your code to write `#define __STATIC_INLINE static inline`.  You can also use `sed` to change code repetitively in numerous places.

Comment: Adding the compiler switch as @DavidGrayson mentioned would require the minimal number of changes.

Comment: the CFLAG -D__STATIC_INLINE='static inline' worked and i no longer get that error. Thank you, I am getting a binch of others now but will have to go trhough them one by one, or possibly use a simulator as recommended by Nguai al which is probably a better choice. as now im getting other errors. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that in some header file there is a line of code that looks like this:

```
#define __STATIC_INLINE static inline
```

The motivation for this ugly hack is to preserve pre-C99 compatibility.
This #define is probably getting removed based on the platform you are compiling on. Cross compiler versus PC platform.

I would work on removing this type of nonsense as the code evolves.

Comment: It is true there is a define as you state, however it comes from an SDK library im using. So i cannot simply remove it as it is present in numerous different files

Answer (score 0):

Check CMSIS, they have these statements in there.

#define __STATIC_INLINE static inline